How can I figure out what's making my site slow?
I'm maintaining a legacy ASP.NET MVC app (on .NET 4.8). One of my pages is unacceptably slow, often taking 30+ seconds to send a response to the browser. I've used MiniProfiler to try to find what's being slow. The results are below:






duration (ms)
with children (ms)
from start (ms)




/Administer/ManageUsers


30530.16
37085.67
+0.00



ManageUsers

414.11
5553.60
+3.93




GetUsers
5118.44
5118.44
+418.00




CreateModel
21.05
21.05
+5536.47



Render: ManageUsers

236.36
1000.70
+5558.86




Render partial: _ManageUsersFilter
726.86
726.86
+5677.21




Render partial: _LoginPartial
13.40
13.40
+6495.95




Render partial: _LoginPartial
11.18
11.18
+6520.76




Render partial: _LoginPartial
10.52
10.52
+6532.08



I've thoroughly covered the controller in profiler calls (e.g., using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("GetUsers"))). In stepping through the code with the debugger, it's clear that the controller accounts for about 20% of the total time. Where's the rest of it coming from?
According to this typical profiling result, the controller is taking about 5.5 seconds and rendering is taking about 1 second. What about the other 24 seconds, that are definitely occurring either during the controller return or after it.
Of course, there are many problems with the code I have the "pleasure" of maintaining, but what I'm trying to solve right now is what's taking those 24 extra seconds.
